# choosing a specific value from a series of values array php

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have an array which looks like this:
I need to have the array in this format for use later in the script.

```
//this is only 1 values set there are others that are returned.
    Array
    (
        [DealerName] => Auto Bavaria Midrand MINI
        [CustomersCounted] => 16
        [Satisfied_Y] => 10
        [Satisfied_N] => 6
        [InterviewDate] => 2012-01-13
    )
```

I have called the array `$customerSatisfactionRatings` which I loop through.

```
foreach($customerSatisfactionRatings as $customerSatisfactionRating) {
      $content .= $customerSatisfactionRating';
    }
```

This returns the correct values into the content variable.
What I am interested in is creating a string from the `[Satisfied_Y]` key.

an example of what I need is `$content = '10,5,15,7,8,9,0,3';`

I know how to make the string, but not how to extract only the `[Satisfied_Y]` key.
This makes me sad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will work. Try this,

```
$satisfyY = array();
foreach($customerSatisfactionRatings as $customerSatisfactionRating) {
      $content .= $customerSatisfactionRating;
      $satisfyY = $customerSatisfactionRating['Satisfied_Y'];
 }
```

Then implode it to make a string.

```
$sat_Y = implode(",", $satisfyY);
```

Comment: I tried this method and all I got was the first letter of each of the array elements:  A, 1 1,6,2  The initial array is a 2D array.  Could that be causing it?

Comment: @user1882752 ya. it might be the problem.

Comment: I have changed the way I get the data so its a standard array and this is working, I will accept the answer when I am able.

Comment: This answer doesn't work in the way that it's currently written.

Answer (score 2):

You use a mapping function to pull every `Satisfied_Y` column out of each `$customerSatisfactionRatings` item and then you join the results together:

```
$content = join(',', array_map(function($item) {
    return $item['Satisfied_Y'];
}, $customerSatisfactionRatings));
```

This assumes that each item in `$customerSatisfactionRatings` is an array as described in your question.

See also: [`array_map()`](http://www.php.net/array_map)

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($customerSatisfactionRatings as $temp)
 if (isset($temp['Satisfied_Y']))
   {
   if (isset($content)) $content.=','.$temp['Satisfied_Y'];
    else $content=$temp['Satisfied_Y'];
   }
```